# Lazy Column in BottomSheetScaffold is not scrollable when BSS is in collapsed state in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I have a lazy column and I want to scroll my lazy list even when my BottomSheetScaffold is in collapse state but it is only scrollable when BottomSheetScaffold is in Expanded state.
When I try to scroll my LazyColumn in collapse state it just expand my bottomsheet. I'm using BottomSheetScaffold not ModalBottomSheetLayout.

Here is the code:

```
    BottomSheetScaffold(
        scaffoldState = bottomSheetScaffoldState,
        modifier = Modifier,
        sheetPeekHeight = 148.aDp,
        backgroundColor = Background,
        sheetGesturesEnabled = true,
        sheetContent = {
            val itemsList = (1..100).toList()

            LazyColumn(
                 modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                 contentPadding = PaddingValues(16.dp)
                ) {
                   items(items = itemsList) { item ->
                   ListItem(item = item)
                  }
               }
            },
         ) {
      // some UI here to show below the bottomsheet
   }

@Composable
fun ListItem(item: Int) {
    Surface(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        color = MaterialTheme.colors.surface
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "Item $item",
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.body1,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
        )
    }
}
```